# Update hrefs in markdown links

Tags: javascript, regex

I understand that this is trivial regex question. But maybe it would be usefull not only for me.

I have markdown file and I need to update its links. Markdown link has format `[TITLE](HREF)`. I have pattern `/\[*\]\(.*?\)/` but it returns incorrect result `](HREF)`.

```js
const line = 'Markdown text [link title](/link/href/name.md#anchor)'
const res = line.match(/\[*\]\(.*?\)/gm);
console.log(res);
```

So how to get just `HREF` (in example it would be `/link/href/name.md#anchor`)

Comment: You may use `/\[[^\][]*\]\([^()]*\)/g`

Comment: What do you expect it to return?!

Comment: Thanks but `/\[[^\][]*\]\([^()]*\)/` returns all `[link title](/link/href/name.md#anchor)`. but i need only `/link/href/name.md#anchor`

Comment: Capture that part - `/\[[^\][]*\]\(([^()]*)\)/g` and get Group 1 value.

Comment: Is it really impossible to solve this in one step?

Comment: @FranzJsel It is possible with ECMAScript 2018.

Comment: thant for nodejs so i dont care about browser support

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with "update its links", but a better approach might be to use an actual markdown parser/processor, such as remark: https://remark.js.org/ . That could also deal with cases such as escaped `[ ]` in the title text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```js
const line = 'Markdown text [link title](/link/href/name.md#anchor)'
const reg = /\[[^\][]*\]\(([^()]*)\)/g;
let m, res = [];
while (m = reg.exec(line)) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

The `/\[[^\][]*\]\(([^()]*)\)/g` regex matches:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\][]*` - 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\]` - a `]` char
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

With the latest ECMAScript implementations you may use

```js
const line = 'Markdown text [link title](/link/href/name.md#anchor)'
console.log(line.match( /(?<=\[[^\][]*\]\()[^()]*(?=\))/g ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern: `\([^\)]+\)$`

`\(` - match `(` literally

`[^\)]+` match one or more characters other than `)`

`\)` - match `)` literally

`$` - match end of string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q3NFdw/1)

Comment: Thats not what i need because its possible to catch just text in brackets, not md link

Comment: @FranzJsel It matches the link :) If it's always at the end, it won't match any other text in brackets - see the demo :)